# How to implement operators in BitwiseOperationsType

Tags: swift

An open source code LogFlag class (CocoaLumberjack.swift no longer compiles because in Xcode 6 Beta 7 RawOptionSetType has been changed to implement BitwiseOperationsType. I am having trouble knowing how to implement the operator functions.

Example below uses LogFlag from CocoaLumberjack.swift:

```
// RawOptionSetType implements BitwiseOperationsType, so LogFlag won't compile until it implements the operators there

struct LogFlag : RawOptionSetType, BooleanType { 
    private var value: Int32 = 0
    init(_ value: Int32) { self.value = value }
    var boolValue: Bool { return self.value != 0 }
    func toRaw() -> Int32 { return self.value }
    static func fromRaw(raw: Int32) -> LogFlag? { return self(raw) }
    static func fromMask(raw: Int32) -> LogFlag { return self(raw) }
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> LogFlag { return self(0) }

    static var Error:   LogFlag { return self(1 << 0) }
    static var Warn:    LogFlag { return self(1 << 1) }
    static var Info:    LogFlag { return self(1 << 2) }
    static var Debug:   LogFlag { return self(1 << 3) }
    static var Verbose: LogFlag { return self(1 << 4) }
}
```

Attempt:

```
func &(_: LogFlag, _:LogFlag) -> LogFlag { // What goes here? }
```

This is the protocol:

```
protocol BitwiseOperationsType {
    func &(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    func |(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    func ^(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    prefix func ~(_: Self) -> Self

    /// The identity value for "|" and "^", and the fixed point for "&".
    ///
    /// ::
    ///
    ///   x | allZeros == x
    ///   x ^ allZeros == x
    ///   x & allZeros == allZeros
    ///   x & ~allZeros == x
    ///
    class var allZeros: Self { get }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to add

```
static var allZeros: LogFlag { return nil }
```

to the struct definition. The remaining operators `&`, `|`, `^` and `~` of the
protocol are already defined as generic functions, e.g.

```
func &<T : _RawOptionSetType>(a: T, b: T) -> T
```

If you actually *want* to override the operator, implement (as an example)

```
func &(a: LogFlag, b: LogFlag) -> LogFlag {
    return LogFlag(a.value & b.value)
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Any idea why I don't have to implement the operators? Also, how would I overload the operator if I want to? Trying to learn more about the syntax.

Comment: @Boon: See update. - (It is impossible to miss that you try to understand all aspects of Swift :)

Comment: You caught it. :) Why are you returning nil for allZeros? nil as I understand is Optional.None right? Why can allZeros return nil when it's not set to return an optional? How can a nil be used in bitwise operation? (as shown in the example of x | allZeros = x)

Comment: @Boon: `RawOptionSetType` inherits from `NilLiteralConvertible`, and creating an option set from `nil` calls the `convertFromNilLiteral()` function, which in turn returns `self(0)`. So you could write `static var allZeros: LogFlag { return self(0) }` instead. – Generally you can use `nil` instead of `SomeOptionSetType(0)`.

Comment: Thank you Martin, appreciate the detailed answer.  Last question: self(0) is the same as LogFlag(0)?

Comment: @Boon: `static` denotes a "type method/property", and inside a type method, `self` denotes the Type object.